# I am trying to upload an image in php to a mysql server. It returns absolutely nothing

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli, wamp

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="input" action="user_registration.php" method="post">
Image: <input type="file" accept="image" name="Image">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the PHP on user_registration.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

It returns "Array ( ) "

I suspect it has something to do with my using a WAMP server. Maybe there are some permissions or something that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works..try this:

```
    <form action="user_registration.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="Image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

I think the accept=Image attribute is wrong..

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. It's also simpler, too, so that's even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="input" action="user_registration.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Image: <input type="file" accept="image" name="Image">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve it. I still get the same result.

Comment: Also this seems not be an answer, but just a code dump sans explanation.